# Specify fields in pyspark when reading from mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

How do I modify this to specify which fields I want to view from the collection? I do not want to view the entire collection

```
df = my_spark.read.format("mongo").option("uri",
        "mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name.collection_name").load()
```

Comment: If you're willing to code against the mongo-spark connector API, then perhaps you can [use aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/aggregation/) and specify a projection in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the number of records you can apply aggregation as stated [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python/aggregation/)

```
pipeline = "{'$match': {'type': 'apple'}}"
df = my_spark.read.format("mongo").option("uri",
        "mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name.collection_name").option("pipeline", pipeline).load()
```

And if you want to specify few columns only then you can read the entire collection then select the required once as spark will lazily evaluate those columns and will apply pushdown predictates

```
df = my_spark.read.format("mongo").option("uri",
        "mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name.collection_name").load().select('column1',column2')
```